# Do a join and merge the foreign document in the same structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections that I am using to build a survey form:

Survey Collection has a document :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbcebfc2436f1d3e6275a5c"),
    "name" : "Some survey name",
    "score" : 12,
    "evidences" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Evidence Method 1",
            "sections" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "section1",
                    "questions" : [ 
                        "QID1", 
                        "QID2"
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "section2",
                    "questions" : [ 
                        "QID3", 
                        "QID4"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Evidence method 2",
            "sections" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "section1",
                    "questions" : [ 
                        "QID5"
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "section2",
                    "questions" : [ 
                        "QID6"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Question Collection has below documents :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbcec1e2436f1d3e6275a6a"),
    "questionId" : "QID1",
    "answer" : "",
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "yes",
            "label" : "YES"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "no",
            "label" : "NO"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbcec322436f1d3e6275a73"),
    "questionId" : "QID2",
    "answer" : "",
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "yes",
            "label" : "YES"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "no",
            "label" : "NO"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe12fd2436f1d3e62795e7"),
    "questionId" : "QID3",
    "answer" : "",
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "yes",
            "label" : "YES"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "no",
            "label" : "NO"
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe130a2436f1d3e62795ef"),
    "questionId" : "QID4",
    "answer" : "",
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "yes",
            "label" : "YES"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "no",
            "label" : "NO"
        }
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe7fdc2436f1d3e627a108"),
    "questionId" : "QID5",
    "answer" : "",
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "yes",
            "label" : "YES"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "no",
            "label" : "NO"
        }
    ]
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe7fe92436f1d3e627a10e"),
    "questionId" : "QID6",
    "answer" : "",
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "yes",
            "label" : "YES"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "no",
            "label" : "NO"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using mongodb 4 and at present using the below query, I am able to join the 2 collections, but what it does is put the referenced doc in a separate field in the document, and I want it to be in the document structure itself.

```
db.createView (
"surveyquestions",
"survey",
    [
        {
                $lookup: {
                from: "questions",
                localField: "evidences.sections.questions",
                foreignField: "questionId",
                as: "question_docs"
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Answer by Veeram, works except that it generates 2 different documents by evidences rather than one as below -

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bbcebfc2436f1d3e6275a5c"),
            "evidences_name" : "Evidence Method 1"
        }
    },
    "name" : "Some survey name",
    "score" : 12,
    "evidences" : [ 
        {
            "sections" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "section1",
                    "questions" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bbcec1e2436f1d3e6275a6a"),
                            "questionId" : "QID1",
                            "answer" : "",
                            "options" : [ 
                                {
                                    "value" : "yes",
                                    "label" : "YES"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "value" : "no",
                                    "label" : "NO"
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bbcec322436f1d3e6275a73"),
                            "questionId" : "QID2",
                            "answer" : "",
                            "options" : [ 
                                {
                                    "value" : "yes",
                                    "label" : "YES"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "value" : "no",
                                    "label" : "NO"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "section2",
                    "questions" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe12fd2436f1d3e62795e7"),
                            "questionId" : "QID3",
                            "answer" : "",
                            "options" : [ 
                                {
                                    "value" : "yes",
                                    "label" : "YES"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "value" : "no",
                                    "label" : "NO"
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe130a2436f1d3e62795ef"),
                            "questionId" : "QID4",
                            "answer" : "",
                            "options" : [ 
                                {
                                    "value" : "yes",
                                    "label" : "YES"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "value" : "no",
                                    "label" : "NO"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bbcebfc2436f1d3e6275a5c"),
            "evidences_name" : "Evidence method 2"
        }
    },
    "name" : "Some survey name",
    "score" : 12,
    "evidences" : [ 
        {
            "sections" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "section1",
                    "questions" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe7fdc2436f1d3e627a108"),
                            "questionId" : "QID5",
                            "answer" : "",
                            "options" : [ 
                                {
                                    "value" : "yes",
                                    "label" : "YES"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "value" : "no",
                                    "label" : "NO"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "section2",
                    "questions" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe7fe92436f1d3e627a10e"),
                            "questionId" : "QID6",
                            "answer" : "",
                            "options" : [ 
                                {
                                    "value" : "yes",
                                    "label" : "YES"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "value" : "no",
                                    "label" : "NO"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

```
db.createView(
    "surveyquestions",
    "survey",
    [
      {"$unwind":"$evidences"},
      {"$unwind":"$evidences.sections"},
      {"$lookup":{
        "from":"questions",
        "localField":"evidences.sections.questions",
        "foreignField":"questionId",
        "as":"evidences.sections.questions"
      }},
      {"$group":{
        "_id":{"_id":"$_id","evidences_name":"$evidences.name"},
        "name":{"$first":"$name"},
        "score":{"$first":"$score"},
        "sections":{"$push":"$evidences.sections"}
       }},
       {"$group":{
         "_id":"$_id._id",
         "name":{"$first":"$name"},
         "score":{"$first":"$score"},
         "evidences":{"$push":{"name":"$_id.evidences_name","sections":"$sections"}}
       }}
     ]
)
```

Comment: Is `survey` the name of the collection ?  Change it to name of your collection probably `Survey`

Comment: did you original query work? I'm not really familiar with the views. All I did was updated your aggregation query.

Comment: So the view query, the one I have put in the question works! And so does the answer you have given, it does the job, when executed as query inside db.survey.aggregate([your aggregation query]) but for some reason not when I use it to create a view like db.createView ()

Comment: okay can you update the post to show your view query that you are trying to run ? I can try at my end.

Comment: I have updated the post with the view query using the aggregation query you supplied.

Comment: Sorry. I've missed the comma after second argument (survey). Updated answer.

Comment: Damn! That worked, although it creates 2 different documents group by evidences, anyway we can avoid that like in a case where we have multiple evidences? - Updated the question with multiple evidences

Comment: Works like a charm! Could you possibly explain the group stages of the pipeline or more so the _id  being used at places and what values do they hold? Thank You!

Comment: You're welcome. Group stage to get back to the original structure after multiple unwinds. For each unwind stage you use group stage. In our case first group with grouping id on evidence and prepare the sections array followed by second group with grouping id on main document to prepare the evidence array.